# Apple not accepting applications built with some versions of the SDK

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm trying to upload a new binary to the app store.
the message i get is: 
"Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK."

Does any one know how to solve it?

Comment: Build with a newer version of the SDK?

Comment: I have the same problem, but i'm building with iPhone SDK 4.0. I'm getting crazy! I really want to upload my app.
Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks,



Jelle

Comment: heya Jelle

I am having the same problem and have posted this same question (for the most part) in another forum that seems to be much more help.

Developer.apple.com

Forums - Getting started

Hopefully someone will answer my question and I can pass it along to you.  If you find out whats going on I'd REALLY appreciate help with this issue also!

Jon

JonLoftis@gmail.com

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem and it's driving me crazy! I have developed my app in the latest SDK (version 3.2.3) but it just won't accept my binary. 

Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is either - I am having the same problem.  I compile the code under SDK 4.0 settings with a deployment target OS of 3.2 or below and it will not work.  I have tried almost every combination of Base SDK and target SDK without any luck.

Comment: i has also crazy two days this same issue. But problem is that i has debug config for my configuration when i prepare bundle. This is not issue of sdk, i guess..

Answer (score 1):

The only way around this is to build against a new version of the SDK.

I believe as of yesterday the minimum version of the SDK is 4.0

Comment: Do you really think it's now impossible to upload binaries that can run under 3.X ??

Comment: In theory, it should work fine on older versions of the OS, as long as none of the functionality of iOS4 is used in the app.  Although I think apple are hoping the vast majority will upgrade since they've made it free for all supported devices.

Comment: And only apps compiled against 4.0 actually get suspended when put in the background.  Apps compiled against < 4.0 get terminated.  They want people to be able to suspend apps to support fast app switching.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it!

The only thing to do is building with a DEVICE SDK and NOT SIMULATOR.
I could submit an app builded with the 3.1 SDK.